# chakra ui - the style does not apply

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

What I expect:
[image]

What actually shows:
[image]

The size is not the same as my expectation.

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { HStack, PinInput, PinInputField } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HStack>
        <PinInput type="alphanumeric">
          <PinInputField />
          <PinInputField />
          <PinInputField />
          <PinInputField />
        </PinInput>
      </HStack>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-snowflake-km87e?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have forgotten the provider setup. Please make sure to read the setup in [the documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/guides/getting-started/cra-guide).

You should have the following code surrouding the App component, helping you fix the problem.

```
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

<ChakraProvider>
  <App />
</ChakraProvider>
```

Comment: This is a problem for me, even tho I have the provider wrapped around the App component

Comment: It is hard to determine the problem you have without seeing the actual code. Have you checked your style imports? What also might help is using a "rubber duck" to explain the steps you have done and see if something is missing. (https://www.masswerk.at/elizabot/)